# Find the maximum possible value of $\frac{A}{\gcd(A,B)} \text{ where } A={100\choose k} \text{ and } B={100\choose k+3}$ such that $30\leq k\leq70$:

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

> For an integer $30\leq k\leq70$, let $M$ be the maximum possible value of 
>   $$\frac{A}{\gcd(A,B)} \text{ where } A={100\choose k} \text{ and } B={100\choose k+3}$$
>   Find $M \mod 100$.

Okay, so directly, lets come to my attempt: 
$$\gcd(a,b)=\frac{a.b}{[a,b]}$$ where $[.]$ denotes the LCM. And then we can apply differentiation to find out the min of the denominator. But what would be the LCM of the two?

Comment: a,b below is A,B right???

Comment: You can, but it is just a general formula which tells that product of two numbers divided by their LCM is GCD. @Freelancer.

Comment: [Related](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X85900137), but probably can't be made to answer your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Slightly more generally, if $A = {n \choose k}$ and $B = {n \choose k+3}$, $0 \le k \le n-3$, we have 
$$ \dfrac{A}{B} = \dfrac{(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}{(n-k)(n-k-1)(n-k-2)}$$
If this is $s/t$ in lowest terms, then $\gcd(A,B) = A/s = B/t$.
You want to maximize (in the case $n=100$ with $30 \le k \le 70$) $A/\gcd(A,B) = s$, i.e. the numerator of $A/B$.  Let $f(k) = (k+1)(k+2)(k+3)$ and 
$g(k) = (100-k)(99-k)(98-k)$, so $$s = \dfrac{f(k)}{\gcd(f(k),g(k)}$$

$(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)$ increases pretty rapidly with $k$, so we should look at large $k$'s.  On the other hand, we want to avoid common factors of $f(k)$ and $g(k)$ as much as possible.  Some common factors are unavoidable: both $f(k)$ and $g(k)$ must be divisible by $6$, because at least one of $k+1,k+2,k+3$ is divisible by $2$ and at least one is divisible by $3$, and similarly for $100-k,99-k,98-k$.  Can we make $\gcd(f(k), g(k)) = 6$?
To avoid having a common factor of $4$ we want to avoid $k \equiv 2$ or $3 (\text{mod } 4)$.  To avoid having a common factor of $5$, we want to avoid $k \equiv 3$ or $4 (\text{mod } 5)$.  This would rule out $k = 62, 63, 64, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70$.  $k = 65$ would be a good candidate, but 
$f(65)$ and $g(65)$ turn out to be divisible by $11$ and $17$.  This leads
us to $61$, where indeed $f(61) =  2^7 \times 3^2 \times 7 \times 31$ and 
$g(61) = 2 \times 3 \times 13 \times 19 \times 37$ have gcd $6$.  Clearly
$$ \dfrac{f(k)}{\gcd(f(k),g(k))} \le \dfrac{f(61)}{6} \ \text{for } 0 < k \le 60 $$ 
while for $62 \le k \le 70$ we have $\gcd(f(k),g(k)) \ge 12$ and $f(k) \le f(70) < 2 f(61)$.  Thus the maximum is 
$$ \dfrac{f(61)}{6} = 41664$$

Comment: Nice answer! +1

Comment: Thank you so much, will award the bounty later (Cannot atm).

Answer (score 1):

According to Mathematica, the maximum is $M=41664$, occurring for $k=61$.

Comment: Do you really think one would award 50 reputation for this and accept it?

Comment: I wouldn't. But it's all I've got. The problem doesn't seem very tractable. I didn't expect an accept, but it wasn't clear to me from your post that you even knew what the answer was. Just trying to help.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, but would have been better if posted as a comment.